# Javascript to clear/unselect item in radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

The initial state of my radiobutton list is all items are clear. If a user accidentally chose an item, I would like them to clear the list by clicking the selected item(unselecting that item).
I would like to use javascript to determine what the state of a radiobutton was before it was clicked. 
What event can I use on the asp.net radiobuttonlist control and what would the javascript function be to determine what was selected.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkRadio()
{
var check= document.getElementById('radio').checked;
alert(check);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkRadio()">

<form action="">
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="true">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>

</body>
</html>
```